# Parsing a file or directory from an semi-random text

Tags: c#, regex, .net-3.5

I've got a method that is going to perform some SVN Commands (using SharpSVN) on a collection of files and or directories, based on what the user has selected within a textbox on the form.

Quickly storing some highlighted text in a variable and looking at it, sample data might be like this:

```
 Modified -- C:\\\folder\\\trunk\\\SubFolderOne\\\SubFolderTwo\\\SubThree\r\nModified -- 
 C:\\\folder\\\trunk\\\SubFolderOne\\\SubFolderTwo\\\SubThree\\\myFile.cs
```

Trying to write a Regex to parse out anything inbetween a Space and the \r character, but I can't figure it out.

I thought the pattern would be something like this:

```
 @"\s\S*\\r"
```

But using my sample data here it yields this as a result:

```
C:\\\folder\\\trunk\\\SubFolderOne\\\SubFolderTwo\\\SubThree\r
```

Then I'm just going to throw each result (ie proper path/file) into a collection of strings which will be used elsewhere in the application.

Is there a better way to do this using the Path class, hopefully?

One thing I can think of would be to split up the data using substring any time it finds `\r\n`, then simply drop the "prefix" `(Modified --, NotVersioned --, Normal --)` from the strings.

That seems really... poor though.

If it helps, I do know the that the top-most directory will always be C:\\folder\\trunk

Comment: You mean, you don't want to get `\r` in the result?

Comment: Do you really need regex for *"parse out anything inbetween a Space and the \r character,"*. Aren't simple string operations enough?

Comment: Jerry: I assume that's a joke? :P
L.B: I suppose I probably could use Substring over and over finding the index of the second space and \r\n
Dmitry: Thank you! That works :)

Comment: Maybe you should use SharpSVN.

Comment: @user1189566 No, that wasn't a joke, and I would have suggested the lookahead (see Dmitry's answer) to do that. Well, I would have simply used `@"\S*(?=\\r|$)"` (the front space isn't necessary in fact and puts that extra space in your result as well, and a lookbehind isn't necessary)

Comment: @Jerry `@"\S+(?=\\r|$)"` to avoid empty matches

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly If there's any empty matches possible yes, but you are using `*` yourself :)

Comment: i have `--\s` so it does not matter, but if you use `Regex.Matches(input, pattern);` with `\S*(?=\\r|$)`, than you will have one empty entry for each \r.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you split the string on `"\r\n"` and then match each string. For example:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"\s(\S*?)$");
foreach (var line in s.Split(new[]{"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    Match m = re.Match(s);
    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},'{2}'", m.Index, m.Length, m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

That works when tested against your sample text.

Comment: Well right, but the problem is the regex doesn't properly parse. First off it appeneded the "r" from the return character on that first half of the text, then it completely disregarded the myFile.cs on the second half.

Comment: @user1189566: I updated the code to be non-greedy. Does that work better? And if it still doesn't work, please supply an example.

Comment: @JimMschel Tried it using both your code and the regex Dmitry provided.

Unfortunately neither worked, your Regex added nothing to the Match collection, and Dmitry's added 1 empty string to it :(

Comment: @user1189566 our code works, but you have given us the wrong input data. I use  `String input = @"Modified -- C:\\\...";` in this context `\r\n` is just symbols but if I don't use `@`, than `\r\n` will be new line symbol and it should be treated differently.

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly well it certainly seems to be working much better now, thanks both of you. Unfortunately though it just seems to add the same string to my collection each iteration of the foreach.

Only difference from my code and what he had posted is that instead of writing to a console, I've got:

files.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regex lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
String pattern = @"(?<=--\s)\S*(?=\\r|$)";
var result = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
foreach (Match match in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);   
}
```

Parsing invalid values is not for `Path` class. You should either use `regex` or `split` and `substring`. Both ways are good, you should prefer the one you can easy read, explain and change.

```
var paths =
    Regex.Split(input, @"\\r\\n")
    .Select(row => row.Substring(row.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1, row.Length - row.LastIndexOf(' ') - 1));
```